# Updating column data using column index and dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to use the `mutate` function to update the values in the first column and achieve the output from the below query -

```
iris %>% head %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#   8.6         3.5          1.4         0.2         setosa
#   7.9         3.0          1.4         0.2         setosa
#   7.9         3.2          1.3         0.2         setosa
#   7.7         3.1          1.5         0.2         setosa
#   8.6         3.6          1.4         0.2         setosa
#   9.3         3.9          1.7         0.4         setosa
```

But by using column index instead of the column name.

```
iris %>% head %>% mutate (  .[[1]] <- .[[1]]+.[[2]])
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species .[[1]] <- .[[1]] + .[[2]]
# 5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2         setosa                    8.6
# 4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2         setosa                    7.9
# 4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2         setosa                    7.9
# 4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2         setosa                    7.7
# 5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2         setosa                    8.6
# 5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4         setosa                    9.3
```

But this creates a new column called `.[[1]] <- .[[1]]+.[[2]])` instead of updating the first column.

Comment: No it isn't in that one it is creating a new column, but in this approach I am trying to update an existing column.

Comment: I think the short answer is that this will not work, simply because `mutate` expects name-value expressions as arguments. The best I can suggest is base R `iris[, 1] <- iris[, 1] + iris[, 2]`.